# How to group by with max date in cosmos db

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I have the following cards container in my cosmos DB:

```
Card: {
    createdAt:"2022-10-17T11:36:53"
    modifiedAt:"2022-10-17T11:36:53"
    id:"49a9f63c-cca6-4424-8eb1-3f742f4c7fef"
    userId:"b66b6801-de31-4ea1-bba7-d77effc2aaaa"
    number : "1234567"
}
```

Each user might have one or more cards. I need a query to select the latest issued card with all details grouped by userId. Is it something possible to achieve with cosmos DB?

Inner queries and self-joins are not supported by Cosmos DB

I tried below SQL query:

```sql
SELECT e.userId, max(e.modifiedAt) as modifiedAt
from Card AS e
WHERE ARRAY_CONTAINS([""], e.userId)
group by e.userId
```

but this gives me only userIds with the latest modified card.